# Prove an inequality involving powers of two

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Let** $a,b,c$ be mutually distinct positive integers.

**Prove** 
$$2^{a+b} + 2^{b+c} + 2^{a+c} < 2^{a+b+c} + 1$$

Any hints on how to start proving it?

Comment: "Mutual distincts" meaning $a,b$ and $c$ are all different? Also, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: It's false if $abc=0$, so perhaps this case should be eliminated.

Comment: @ArnaudD. That requires one of $a, b, c = 0$ but $0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I generally consider that $0\in \Bbb N$. I know some people don't, so I thought asking for some clarification would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the set of Natural Numbers to be $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3 \ldots \}$

Let $$\alpha =2^{-a} + 2^{-b} + 2^{-c}$$

And

$$\beta =1+2^{-(a+b+c)}$$

We can easily see that the maximum value of $\alpha$ will occur for minimum values of $a,b$, and $c$.

The minimum values of $a,b$ and $c$ , are $1,2$, and $3$ (All are distinct).

Hence $$\alpha =2^{-a} + 2^{-b} + 2^{-c} \le 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-3}=\frac 78$$

And we also have $\beta$ :

$$2^{-(a+b+c)} \gt 0 \implies \beta= 1+2^{-(a+b+c)} \gt 1$$

Thus we have :

> $$\alpha \le \frac78 ~~{and}~~ \beta \gt 1$$

Hence, obviously $\alpha \lt \beta$

Now multiplying both the sides by any positive quantity won't change the inequality, so we multiply both the sides by $2^{a+b+c}$

Hence, finally we get :

> $$2^{a+b} + 2^{b+c} + 2^{a+c} < 2^{a+b+c} + 1$$

Comment: This is great! Well explained.

Comment: You have assumed what you want to prove. Your argument can easily be saved, but as it is written, it proves nothing.

Comment: @robjohn I have corrected my argument now.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the left-hand side is a sum of distinct powers of $2$, so (assuming WLOG that $a < b < c$)
$$2^{a+b}+2^{b+c}+2^{a+c}<\sum_{k=0}^{b+c}2^k=2^{b+c+1}-1<2^{a+b+c}+1.$$

Comment: This answer is nice. I wish I would've thought of this! (+1)

Comment: @Arnaud. Nice answer. Please clarify: Sum, k=0 to k= b+c is equal to $2^{b +c +1}$ - $2^0$ . NB.You use = sign. Next: $\lt$, then multiply $ 2^a$ to get result. Am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing $-1$, I've fixed that. For the second inequality, I used the fact that $1\leq a$, and thus $2^{1+b+c} \leq 2^{a+b+c}$ (the strict inequality comes from the added $-1<1$).

Answer (score 1):

It can also be proven by induction.

Assume it's true for $(a,b,c)$. Then:

\begin{align}
2^{a+b+(c+1)}+1&=2\cdot 2^{a+b+c}+2-1\\
&=2\cdot 2^{a+b+c}+2-1\\
&=2(2^{a+b+c}+1)-1\\
&>2(2^{a+b}+2^{b+c}+2^{c+a})-1\\
&>2^{a+b}+2^{b+(c+1)}+2^{(c+1)+a}+2^{a+b}-1\\
&>2^{a+b}+2^{b+(c+1)}+2^{(c+1)+a}\\
\end{align}

Note that we didn't assume $a,b,c$ are distinct, or anything about the order. Thus, from $(a,b,c)$ we can not only derive $(a,b,c+1)$, but also $(a,b+1,c)$ and $(a+1,b,c)$. Now check the base case:

$$2^{1+2}+2^{2+3}+2^{3+1}<2^{1+2+3}+1$$

so that it's true for all $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$ (such that they are larger than $1$, $2$ and $3$; they don't have to be distinct, but we still needed that for the base case).

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for correcting that, it's fixed